# Property from service update loop but not interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service in which I have `mode` of type string and `el` which is an array. I have two methods - one is changing string and one is pushing new element to array.

```
export class StoreService {
    public mode = 'light';
    public el = ['aa', 'bb'];

    setMode(newMode: string) {
        this.mode = newMode;
    }

    addEl() {
        this.el.push('');
    }
}
```

Currently I use this service only in one component so I'm not providing it in module but just in component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {StoreService} from '../../../../../services/store.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-modes',
    templateUrl: './modes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modes.component.scss'],
    providers: [StoreService]
})

export class ModesComponent implements OnInit {
    mode: boolean;
    modeFromStore: string;
    el = [];

    constructor(private storeService: StoreService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.el = this.storeService.el;
        this.modeFromStore = this.storeService.mode;
    }

    modeChanged() {
        this.storeService.addEl();
        if (this.mode) {
            this.storeService.setMode('dark');
        } else {
            this.storeService.setMode('light');
        }
    }
```

As you can see in component I have this mode change method which for now execute these two methods from service.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mode" (change)="modeChanged()">
{{ mode }} i: {{ modeFromStore }}
<span *ngFor="let i of el">{{ i }};</span>
```

finally, in HTML I have interpolation with my string from service and I have a loop on my array from service.

My question is why when I execute `modeChanged` I can clearly see that new element is added to the array because I see it in view but the interpolated string is not updating? I would consider this as logical if either both do not update or both updates. But here interpolated string remains the same but loop got new element and updates. Further how to force string to update aswell?

Comment: Looks like in your `modeChanged()` you need to set the value for `modeFromStore` as well.

Comment: If possible a stackblitz will be helpful to pinpoint the exact reason.

Comment: I created a stackbiz with the code you put in and I don't have that problem, take a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqmnn9

Comment: I want `{{ modeFromStore }}` to be changing between light and dark in stackblitz you can see that it's not updating value in rendered view.

Comment: Ok, excuse me, I didn't understand your question correctly, you should make a  getter in service and use it in component, or create this service property as an observable and subscribe to it from the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `modeChanged()` you need to set the value for `modeFromStore` in order for the changes to get reflected:

The best way would be to add a BehaviourSubject to the service:

```
export class StoreService {

   // .... 

   bhs: BehaviorSubject<string>;

   constructor() {
      this.bhs = new BehaviorSubject('light');
   }

   setMode(newMode: string) {
      this.bhs.next(newMode);
   }

}
```

Now you can retrieve the *mode* in your current component or in any other component.

hello.component.ts (or any other component)

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.el = this.storeService.el;
   this.storeService.bhs.subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.modeFromStore = res;
      }
    );
}
```

Here's a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdc7ca) for the same.

Comment: Yes but later I will also want to inject this service into other component and there I will also need value to bind some styles depending on if it's light or dark. And there I will not have modeChanged function. I need some other way to watch for its change.

Comment: I've updated the answer since your comment, could you pls recheck if that issue still persists after the edit?

Comment: Now if you want to retrieve this value in any other component you just need to *inject* the service and invoke the `getMode()` method.

Comment: But I don't really think that it's gonna update in other component. If it does why would I need to execute this getMode in both places after seting it. Look, it won't update in another component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtpxjs?file=src/app/hello.component.ts I would need to use EventEmitter additionally to know when to use getMode() but I don't want to do that

Comment: My question was at first about why loop is updated in view on every change although I'm not subscribing but interpolation is not and then how to make interpolation updating realtime

Comment: Because that's actually what confuse me - that I assign array from service to variable in component and then execute method in component which execute method in service which push to array in service and then magically in component assigned variable got updated and it got updated in html as well. But same mechanism does not apply string. Why?

Comment: Yes, you are right you would need a EventEmitter to make it get reflected in another component. To answer your question `modeFromStore` is never changed after you toggle the checkbox whereas `e1` is a reference to an array that is pointing to the *services's* array object.

Comment: Yes and listen for event in every component where I will want to get this value, that's not what I want. I wanted to have shared value something like store but smaller. Should I create observable? Could you show me how to make this service property as an observable and subscribe to it in component?

Comment: I've edited the answer to make use of `BehaviourSubject` which will have an initial value. Now in *any* component you can just subscribe to it.